# How to run duplex communication using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I have 3 Raspberry Pi's, all on the same LAN doing stuff that is monitored by Python and I want them to talk to each other, and to my PC. Sockets seem like the way to go, but the examples are so simplistic. Here's the issue I am stuck on - the listen and receive processes are all blocking, unless you set a timeout, in which case they still block, just for less time.

So, if I set up a round-robin, then each Pi will only be listened to (or received on) for 1/3 of the time, or less if there is stuff to transmit as well.

What I'd like to understand better is what happens to the data (or connection requests) when I am not listening/receiving - are these buffered by the OS, or lost..? What happens to the socket when there is no method called, is it happy to be ignored for a while, or will the socket itself be dumped by the OS..?

I am starting to split these into separate processes now, which is getting messy and seems inefficient, but I can't think of another way except to run this as 3 (currently), maybe 6 (transmit/receive) or even 9 (listen/transmit/receive) separate processes..?

Sorry I don't have a code example, but it is already way tooo big, and it doesn't work. plus a lot of the issue seems to me to be in the murky part of the sockets - that part between the socket and the OS. I feel I need to understand this better to get to the right architecture for my bit of code before I really start debugging the various exceptions and communication failures...

Comment: Data arriving through sockets are definitely buffered by the OS.

Comment: If you want a single receiver to be able to process multiple channels, `select` or the higher level module `selectors` are the way to go. Both use the underlying `select` system call to wait for a number of socket events (data available, new connection, etc.) to monitor multiple sockets in a single execution thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle multiple sockets in a single process using *I/O multiplexing*. This is usually done using calls such as `epoll()`, `poll()` or `select()`. These calls monitor multiple sockets and return when one or more sockets have data available for reading. Or are ready to write data to. In many cases this is more convenient than using multiple processes and/or threads.

[These calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) are pretty low level OS calls. Python seems to have [higher level functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) that might be easier to use but I haven't tried this myself.